# How to make the letter "A" an exception in Lucene's StandardAnalyzer?

Tags: java, android, lucene, lexical-analysis, standardanalyzer

I've created a medical dictionary in Android using Lucene. The words and definitions are Danish, and I'm using `StandardAnalyzer` to index and search for the entries. The idea is that when I click on an entry in my `ListView`, another `Activity` shows up with the word on top and the definition below it.

The dictionary works exactly as expected EXCEPT for the entry `A.`. When I click on `A.` in my `ListView`, the next `Activity` shows only the screen's background colors--no word, no definition, no any kind of text.

My guess is that `StandardAnalyzer` counts the letter `A` as a stop word during the indexing process, because the `Activity` for the entry `V.` shows up correctly. How can I get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `DanishAnalyzer`. Probably better that way, anyway.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `StandardAnalyzer` with a different set of stop words.

For the default stop words see `StandardAnalyzer.STOP_WORDS_SET`, it is copied from [`StopAnalyzer.ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS_SET`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.lucene/lucene-core/3.5.0/org/apache/lucene/analysis/StopAnalyzer.java#StopAnalyzer.0ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS_SET).

```
new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_35, stopWordsSet);
```